# Infer generic lambda parameters from another generic lambda's parameters

Tags: python, mypy

Consider the following code:

```py
from typing import Callable, TypeVar

T = TypeVar('T')

def middle_man(
    producer: Callable[[], T],
    consumer: Callable[[T], None]
) -> None:
    consumer(producer())

middle_man(
    lambda: "HELLO",
    lambda s: print(s.lower())
)
```

This code runs without error and works as expected, however, mypy fails to infer the type of `s` in the second lambda, giving the error:

> "object" has no attribute "lower"`

Right now, my only workaround is either to cast `s`, which can be a pain in a more complex lambda or with a more complex type, or to add `# type: ignore`, which I'd rather not do.

Is there a better workaround, or a proper way to get mypy to recognize the type?

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me that you have two conflicting concerns here:

- you want your `T` `TypeVar` to be generic so that the type annotation for the `producer` and `consumer` parameters to `middle_man` can be flexible
- you want the type annotations for a specific call to `middle_man` to be specific enough that `mypy` recognizes that you are calling it with a `str` type

In order to achieve this, I would annotate the arguments to a specific call to `middle_man` by storing the arguments as variables first:

```
from typing import Callable, TypeVar

T = TypeVar('T')

def middle_man(
    producer: Callable[[], T],
    consumer: Callable[[T], None]
) -> None:
    consumer(producer())

producer: Callable[[], str] = lambda: "HELLO"
consumer: Callable[[str], None] = lambda s: print(s.lower())

middle_man(producer, consumer)
```

**EDIT**

Another suggestion:

Since you are using a generic `TypeVar` anyway, you can replace it with the `Any` type without losing type information and `mypy` will not raise an error because it [skips static type checking for `Any` types](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/kinds_of_types.html#the-any-type).

```
from typing import Callable, Any

def middle_man(
    producer: Callable[[], Any],
    consumer: Callable[[Any], None]
) -> None:
    consumer(producer())

middle_man(
    lambda: "HELLO",
    lambda s: print(s.lower())
)
```

I know this solution is not very satisfying because it essentially defeats the purpose of using `mypy` for static type checking but unless you want to [restrict the upper bound of your `TypeVar`](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/generics.html#type-variables-with-upper-bounds) to a class with a `lower` method then this might be your best option.

Comment: The whole point of using a lambda expression is to *avoid* pre-defining it. If you are going to name the result of the lambda expression, you should just use a `def` statement.

Comment: @chepner I agree that not having to predefine a `lambda` is an advantage (saying that's the _whole_ point might be a little strong). If not predefining `lambda`s matters  for this question then I suggest OP either disregards my solution or redefines his producer and consumers as `def` statements as you suggest.

Comment: There is no function that you can define with a lambda expression that you can't define with a `def` statement, so yes, there's no reason to use a `lambda` expression if you aren't actually using the result as an anonymous function. PEP-8 [*explicitly*](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#programming-recommendations) calls out using lambda expressions in this fashion.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  This is certainly better than casting `s` or using `# type: ignore`.  I agree with chepner, though, that I might as well use `def` instead of `lambda` in this situation (it would actually be shorter and easier to read).  I still wish I could rely on inference, but this is better than what I'm doing now.